# open an excel file from a folder without using Directory name

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to know, if there is a way to open the excel file by just searching for the folder and opening the excel file in the folder.

I am having my excel file In the folder Downloads and it is in xlsx format. I have my working excel file also in the same folder . which is xlsm format.

I want to open the excel file with the folder name and not the directory name.

I have searched through internet and fount we could mention

userfilename = thisworkbook.path
file = (Userfile & ".xlsx" , vbnormal)

But I am struck how to proceed further and how this works.

Could anyone help me with this ?

Comment: Can you please help me to solve this requirement

Comment: folder = directory! Only issue you may have is it converts names with spaces to something like %20, or you quote path if calling from DOS. Or folder gets a truncated name with a unique identifier - something like xxxxxx~1 xxxxxx~2 etc

Answer (score 2):

```
Try this code:   

Sub Main()
    Dim W As Workbook
    Set W = ActiveWorkbook
    FromPath = W.Path & "\"  'Actual Workbook Folder
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.filesystemobject")
    Set objFolder = fso.GetFolder(FromPath)
    For Each FileInFolder In objFolder.Files    'Find All File in Folder
        If (InStr(1, FileInFolder.Name, ".xlsx") Or InStr(1, FileInFolder.Name, ".xlsm") Or InStr(1, FileInFolder.Name, ".xls")) And Left(FileInFolder.Name, 2) <> "~$" Then 'Check is correct format
            If FileInFolder.Name <> W.Name Then 'Check is not equal actual file
                    Workbooks.Open (FileInFolder.Name) 'Open
                    Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    Next FileInFolder
End Sub
```